# Return 1 Record if All are False for ID

Tags: sql

I am trying to come up with a query that returns a list of parts where all of the flags for that one part are false, and the returned list should only have one record returned for that part.

```
Part   Revision   Flag
Part1|   A      | true
Part1|   B      | false
Part2|   C      | false
Part2|   D      | false
Part2|   E      | false
Part3|   A      | true
Part4|   F      | false
```

Output:

```
Part               Revision               Flag
Part2|   C(or any other revision)      | false
Part4|   F                             | false
```

Part1 and Part3 have at least 1 flag set to true so they don't get outputted.  Part2 and 4 have no flags at all set to true, and Part2 only returns 1 row for all of them.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [PartNum],[RevisionNum],[Flag]
        FROM [Prod].[Erp].[PartRev]
        WHERE RevisionNum is not null AND Approved = 0
ORDER BY PartNum
GROUP BY [PartNum],[RevisionNum],[Flag]
```

So far I can get one row per part number, but it will return just one row even if one of the others for that part number is true.

What gets returned:

```
Part   Revision   Flag
Part1|   B      | false
Part2|   C      | false
Part4|   F      | false
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: you might need a subquery or a self-referencing join to check for positive rows for the same part ID. Or depending on your RDBMS there might be a nicer way

Comment: @Mureinik Sql Server Management Studio

Comment: Something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c041ec/7

Comment: @bubbajake00 SQL Server Management Studio isn't an RDBMS. SQL Server is your RDBMS. Management Studio is just one of many programs which can be used to interact with a SQL Server database engine. You may think I'm being pedantic but in programming that's not a bad thing necessarily...it helps to use the right terminology and also to understand the purpose and the different components involved in the tools you're using.

Comment: @ADyson I very much appreciate your explanation!  I hadn't seen term before so I guess my Google Search wasn't as accurate as I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, select all of the records that have flag = true

```
SELECT DISTINCT Part FROM PartRev WHERE flag = 1 --or whatever your RDBMS uses for a true value
```

Then, select all the distinct records that are not included in the first query. So, the query would look like this

```
SELECT Part, MIN(Revision), flag
FROM PartRev WHERE Part NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Part FROM PartRev WHERE flag = 1
)
GROUP BY Part, flag
```

Comment: This was pretty simple and I've got it working now!  I've been looking at this on and off for the past few days, so thank you for solving my frustration!

Answer (score 2):

Another option

```
Select Part 
      ,Revision = max(Revision)
      ,Flag     = max(flag)
 from  YourTable
 Group By Part
 Having max(Flag)='false'
```

Returns

```
Part    Revision    Flag
Part2   E           false
Part4   F           false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` to not pull any records that have a `true` flag.

It also looks like you're wanting to pull the most recent revision for the part as the record returned, which can be accomplished via a `ROW_NUMBER()` and selecting just the most recent record.

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By Part Order By Revision Desc) As RN
    From    [Prod].[Erp].[PartRev]  P1
    Where   RevisionNum is not null 
    And     Approved = 0
    And Not Exists
    (
        Select  *
        From    [Prod].[Erp].[PartRev]  P2
        Where   P1.Part = P2.Part
        And     P2.Flag = 'true'
    )
)
Select  Part, Revision, Flag
From    Cte
Where   RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this, as a more general formulation, because the case statement can be made quite complex:

```
SELECT 
 SP.Part
 , SP.Revision
 , SP.Flag 
 FROM ( 
     SELECT 
       Part
       , Count(Part) as TC
       , SUM( CASE Flag WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) FC
       , MAX(Revision) AS Revision 
       , MAX(flag) AS Flag
     FROM test 
     GROUP BY Part 
     ) SP
 WHERE SP.TC=SP.FC
```